# JQuery UI - trying to open an accordion section where accordions are in separate tabs

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, accordion

I'm new to JQuery and I'm having problems trying to get a function to work where I have a link to an anchor within an JQuery UI accordion within a tab on a page. I have separate accordions (2) in 2 tabs (1 in @ tab). I've pieced together some code that sort of works and sort of doesn't. Here's what I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

  // Accordion
  $('#accordion2, #accordion3').accordion({ header: "h3",navigation: true,collapsible: true });

  // Tabs
            $('#tabs').tabs();

            // Tabs                                                                                                              
    var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();

    // Handle clicks for on-page accordion section links                                                                                  
   $("a.openTab").click(function(e) {
        var thisName = "";
        var $tabParent = null;
        var tabIndex = 0;
                    var $accordionParent = null;
        var accordionIndex = 0;

        // Prevent default click behavior                                                                            
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the named anchor from the clicked link's href                                                         
        thisName = $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];

        // Find the tab parent. Tabs should all have class "tab".                                                    
        $tabParent = $("a[name='" + thisName + "']").closest(".tab");

                    // Find the accordion parent. Accordion should all have class "accTable".                                                    
        $accordionParent = $("a[name='" + thisName + "']").closest(".accTable");

        // Get the index of this tab                                                                                 
        tabIndex = $(".tab").index($tabParent);

                    // Get the index of this accordion                                                                                 
        accordionIndex = $(".accTable").index($accordionParent);
                    // alert(accordionIndex);

        // Open the appropriate tab                                                                                  
        $tabs.tabs("select", tabIndex);

                    // Open the appropriate accordion section
                                            $('.accordionTabs').accordion( "option", "active", accordionIndex );

                    // Scroll down to selected opened accordion                             
              $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop:$("a[name='" + thisName + "']").offset().top
                        }, 2000);
    });




        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<DIV id=wrapper>

    <BR><BR>
        <a class="openTab" href="#tab1">Target anchor in tab 1</a><BR>
    <a class="openTab" href="#tab2">Target anchor in tab 2</a><BR>
  <a class="openTab" href="#tab3">Target anchor in tab 3</a><BR>
        <a class="openTab" href="#ServicesSkill">Services anchor within tab 2</a><BR>
        <a class="openTab" href="#SolutionsSkill">Solution anchor within tab 2</a><BR>
        <a class="openTab" href="#EducationSkill">Education anchor within tab 3</a><BR>
        <a class="openTab" href="#CustomerSkill">Customer anchor within tab 3</a><BR>
    <BR><BR><BR>



    <!-- Tabs -->
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-1" class="tab">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
        exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <a name="tab1">This is a named anchor in tab 1.</a>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-2" class="tab">
        <p>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet 
        ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum bibendum.</p>
   <a name="tab2">This is a named anchor in tab 2.</a>

            <div id="accordion2" class="accordionTabs">
                <div>
                    <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
                    <div class="accTable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3><a href="#">Services</a></h3>
                    <div class="accTable">
                    <a name="ServicesSkill"></a>
                    Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3><a href="#">Solutions</a></h3>
                    <div class="accTable">
                    <a name="SolutionsSkill"></a>
                    Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
                </div>
            </div>          

        </div>

        <div id="tabs-3" class="tab">
            <div id="accordion3" class="accordionTabs">
                <div>
                    <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
                    <div class="accTable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3><a href="#">Education</a></h3>
                    <div class="accTable">
                    <a name="EducationSkill"></a>
                    Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3><a href="#">Customer</a></h3>
                    <div class="accTable">
                    <a name="CustomerSkill"></a>
                    Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <P>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis, sollicitudin eu, felis. Pellentesque
        nisi urna, interdum eget, sagittis et, consequat vestibulum, lacus. Mauris porttitor 
        ullamcorper augue.</P>
  <a name="tab3">This is a named anchor in tab 3.</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It will open anchors in the 1st accordion I have in the 1st tab but it goes wonky when trying to open a link to any anchor in the 2nd accordion I have in the 2nd tab. I modified a 'openTab' function I found elsewhere here and added code to also try to get it to open the accordion section that has the anchor. I can't seem to figure out what I have wrong that it will open the sections in the first accordion okay but it goes wrong when trying to get a section to open in the 2nd accordion in the 2nd tab. It seems to be finding the index of the accordion section correctly as well as the tab Index the accordion is in. It either won't open the section or sometimes it selects it and won't open the content within the section. After trying to use the function to open 2nd accordion section, the section won't even open when manually clicking the accordion header. This has been driving me crazy trying to figure out the problem. Does anyone have any ideas on what I've done wrong? (Sorry if the coding isn't indented. It's my first posting here) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you look up the index of the accordion panel you want to open you're searching through all the accordion panels on the page, not just the ones in the current accordion. That's why your index is working for the first tab, but not for the second tab. The number is off by the number of accordion panels in the first tab.

Change

```
// Get the index of this accordion                                                                                 
accordionIndex = $(".accTable").index($accordionParent);
```

to

```
// Get the index of this accordion panel within this tab                                                                             
accordionIndex = $accordionParent.closest('.accordionTabs').find('.accTable').index($accordionParent);
```

Additional comments:

1. You have an unnecessary level of divs surrounding your accordion
   panels
2. You're not checking to make sure you've clicked on an anchor that's contained in an accordion before trying to set the active accordion panel
3. You should only be changing the active accordion panel for the current accordion, not all of them.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/3p5QG/